# How to solve "NameError: name 'x' is not defined" in pycharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I had a problem while coding I tried to solve it by abstracting the non-problematic parts and making a new Pycharm project with only the problematic part so that I can see it more clearly but I still can't see any problems. I think it may be because of a software error but I am not sure

**Here is the problematic part:**

```
import sys
import os

User_Name=str(input("What is your name?"))
print (User_Name)
```

**Here is the outcome:**

> What is your name? #X Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/More_Complex_Projects/BLINDFOLDED.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       User_Name=str(input("What is your name?"))   File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'X' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

I expected it to print out the variable User_Name but it just gives an Name error

Comment: Use `raw_input` in Python2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're using Python 2. In this case, you should use `raw_input`, which doesn't attempt to parse the inputted string and not `input`:

```
user_name = raw_input("What is your name?")
# Here -----^
```

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research :

- for python 2.7 https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input
- for python 3.X https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Now what you have is 2.7 , therefore you should tend to use raw_input() rather than the input().

Try :

```
import sys
import os

User_Name=str(raw_input("What is your name?"))
print (User_Name)
```